# не удалось скопировать файл "obj\Debug\{ProjectName}.exe" - файл не найден

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

При сборке решения своего проекта wpf довольно часто  получаю ошибку:

```
не удалось скопировать файл "obj\Debug\{ProjectName}.exe" - файл не найден.
```

Я не первый, кто столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Пробовал много различных советов, таких, как смена версии целевой платформы, обновление .net framework, переустановка visual studio и т.д.
Единственной, что мне помогает, это перезапук visual studio (не каждый раз срабатывает).
А самое удивительное для меня, что всегда помогает изменение AssemblyVersion в файле AssemblyInfo.cs, я просто изменяю цифру в версии с 1.0.0.0 (дефолт) на 2.0.0.0 и решение собирается без ошибок, но через некоторое время ошибка появляется снова и тогда приходится изменять версию снова.

```
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Для меня остается секретом суть данной проблемы, подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне окончательно избавиться от этой ошибки.

PS: решение небольшое, состоит из одного одностраничного проекта WPF и библиотеки .dll, написанной мной, но вне данного решения, библиотека работает без проблем.
Из сторонних библиотек использую Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls для взаимодействия с картой

UPD: Данная проблема появилась и в других проектах WPF, в том числе и тех, что не используют сторонние библиотеки.
В не WPF проектах (WinForms, DLL-library, Console Application) получить ошибку так и не получилось

UPD2:
Заметил, что при сборке решения, все ошибки дублируются.
Код, вызывающий ошибку

```
InputErrors inputErrors = new InputErrors(initData); // конструктор не принимает аргумент initData
SaveInitDataHandler += inputErrors.InputErrors_SaveInitDataHandler //пропущено ";"
```

[image: Скриношот ошибок:]

Comment: `Я не первый, кто столкнулся с подобной проблемой.` - если это баг, то обращайтесь к авторам, пусть фиксят. `Пробовал много различных советов` - а такие советы, как "новый, чистый проект", "удалить из проекта сторонние библиотеки", "удалить из студии лишние расширения" пробовали? То есть, я хочу сказать, что это скорей всего вы где-то накосячили, либо поставили что-то лишнее, выясните что именно.

Comment: У меня тоже есть куча проектов в Visual Studio, о вашей проблеме впервые слышу.

Comment: Да, я не сомневаюсь, что это я сам накосячил, но я не могу найти источник проблемы. После переустановки visual studio, где не было установлено никаких расширений и т.д. эта ошибка появилась при первой же сборке проекта, возможно, что то не так с ОС. Но я не понимаю как с этим связано изменение AssemblyVersion.
Также вчера получил эту ошибку и в других "чистых" проектах WPF, которые не используют сторонних библиотек

Comment: Возможно, ваш проект после предыдущего отладочного запуска не был завершён и продолжает висеть в памяти. Посмотрите в Диспетчере задач: если найдёте там свой проект - значит причина в этом. Убейте его. И добавьте перехват исключений в свой код.

Comment: откройте csproj файл в текстовом редакторе и проверьте на наличие подозрительных инструкций (например, PostBuildEvent). также отлючите все Extensions->Manage Extensions, Installed. обновите свою Visual Studio до последней версии (Help->Check for Updates)

Comment: В проектах вроде бы нет ничего подозрительного, сравнил с проектами на работе, собирающихся без ошибок на рабочей машине, и не увидел чего-то необычного. Попробовал отключить все расширения и обновил до последней версии. На ошибку это никак не повлияло.
Заметил, что при наличии какой-то синтаксической ошибки, visual studio выводит каждую ошибку дважды, как будто у меня собирается не один проект, а 2 идентичных, пример добавил в исходных вопрос. 
Большое спасибо за помощь и уделенное время!

Comment: Боюсь Вы меня не так поняли, суть не в том, что синтаксические ошибки присутствуют, а в том, что они дублируют друг друга в рамках одного проекта